# How to display the specific message in X seconds and automatically disappear please help to solve the problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The below code displays Welcome user from Firebase, but I want that welcome message to show only for X seconds... Please help me to customize the code as I'm new to flutter and I'm exploring some custom message and doing it. Please help to solve the problem

```
     class _DashboardPageState extends State<Dashboard> {
              final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
              User? user;
              var name = '';
              
            
              @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();
                initUser();
              }
            
              initUser() async {
                user = (await _auth.currentUser!);
                name = user!.displayName!;
                setState(() {});
              }
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataInfoPage()));
                      },
                    ),
                    body: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Welcome " + name,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: Please share whole code!

Comment: thats the code i have written

Comment: this code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Run below code it will solved your problem!

```
  class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
          bool showWidget = false;
        
          recieveResponseFromTimer() {
            setState(() {
              showWidget = true;
            });
          }
        
          setTimer() {
            var duration = Duration(seconds: 10);
            return Timer(duration, recieveResponseFromTimer);
          }
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            setTimer();
            super.initState();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child:
                      (showWidget): Text('')?Text("Please show me for 10 seconds"),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```